# How to plot a heatmap of [x y z] data?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a numpy array of a size 10000x3, of a format[[x1 y1 z1], [x2,y2,z2],...], which I want to plot in a form of a heatmap.

All the pyplot examples I have so far dealt with require passing a plotting function an X vector of length N, an Y vector of length M and then some form of Z with a total of M elements.

Is there a way to just pass the whole array of xyz data without extracting x,y and z?